# Ставится ли в данном случае запятая

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Есть вопрос: нужно ли в предложении ниже ставить запятую перед словом «родился»? Что-то подсказывает, что да, но, какое здесь правило, понять не могу. Если запятая действительно нужна, то почему?

«Изначально здесь должны были быть только фотографии, но при попытке коротко описать происходящее(,) родился целый рассказ».

Answer (score 1):

3апятая не нужна, т. к. вторая часть сложного предложения( от слова "но") представляет собой обычное простое предложение, оно не содержит элементов, требующих выделения(нет обособленных, уточняющих, однородных членов и т.д.)

Comment: А  обстоятельственный оборот "при попытке коротко описать происходящее" можно обособить?   В конце оборота делается пауза,  может быть, ее  нужно обозначить запятой?

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите сделать там паузу, надо поставить интонационное тире, но не запятую:
*Изначально здесь должны были быть только фотографии, но при попытке коротко описать происходящее — родился целый рассказ.*
Это здесь целесообразно, потому что получился неожиданно большой результат, так как одна из функций интонационного тире — выражение неожиданности.

Правило Розенталя:
Тире, которое ставится между членами предложения **для выражения неожиданности** или для обозначения логического ударения, также имеет интонационный характер:
*И щуку бросили — в реку.

Через несколько минут загремели цепи, двери отворились, и вошёл — Швабрин.*
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=94

Если пауза не нужна, то и тире не нужно. А запятая там точно не подходит.

Примеры, которые нашёл shampar:

> Причём обычно две эти жидкости при попытке их смешать тут же разделяются ― более лёгкая оказывается наверху. [Е. Клещенко. Домашний майонез // «Кот Шрёдингера», 2016]
>
> Их арестовали, заставили сесть в грузовик на дно кузова, вытянув ноги, и предупредили: «При попытке бегства и если подберете ноги ― стреляем без предупреждения». [Геннадий Горелик. Андрей Сахаров. Наука и свобода (2004)]

Comment: Разве примеры  с двумя глаголами менее уместны?

Comment: Что за примеры с двумя глаголами?

Comment: То, что названо простым предложением (см. Анна Кельсиева), содержит два глагола-сказуемых, а в примере из Розенталя (2) тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым. Есть ли примеры, более подходящие к заданному вопросу?

Comment: Розенталь: Такое тире, называемое интонационным, может отделять **любую часть предложения**.

Comment: Есть ли примеры, более подходящие к заданному вопросу?

Comment: Где? У Розенталя. Ссылка в ответе. У Лопатина что-то не вижу этой темы.